# Get the next x days excluding weekends and show them all

Tags: php

I am having some difficulties display the next x number of days excluding weekends. The basic code is here which displays all days:

```
<?php

for($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    echo date('D M j', strtotime("$i day"));
}

?>
```

I cant then get it to do a continue:

```
<?php

for($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    $day = date('N', strtotime("$i day"));
    if($day == '6' || $day == '7') continue;
    echo date('D M j', strtotime("$i day"));
}

?>
```

But this obviously skips the weekends completely and I don't get x returned days. I have tried reducing the number by 1 but just get timeouts so guessing this is not the way to go.

Comment: Don’t make the `$i < 8` part in the for loop static, use a variable instead. Instead of continue, increase that variable by one, when your if condition is true, and do the echo of the date in the else branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CBroe already pointed out, use a variable for the number of days you want to iterate. When you get a saturday or sunday then increment that variable by one. E.g.

```
<?php

$x = 8;
for($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++) {
    $day = date('N', strtotime("$i day"));
    if($day == '6' || $day == '7') {
        $x++;
        continue;
    }
    echo date('D M j', strtotime("$i day"));
}

?>
```

The output would always be `$x` weekdays, for today it would be

```
Fri Jan 22Mon Jan 25Tue Jan 26Wed Jan 27Thu Jan 28Fri Jan 29Mon Feb 1Tue Feb 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were to adopt the `DateTime` class you could do like this:

```
    $start=new DateTime();
    $end=new DateTime('now + 7days');
    $interval=new DateInterval('P1D');
    
    $start->sub( $interval );
    while( $start < $end ){
        $start->add( $interval );
        $N=intval($start->format('N'));
        if( $N > 0 && $N < 6 ){
            echo $start->format('l N Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br />';
        }
    }
```

Which yields output like:

```
Friday 5 2021-01-22 13:22:01
Monday 1 2021-01-25 13:22:01
Tuesday 2 2021-01-26 13:22:01
Wednesday 3 2021-01-27 13:22:01
Thursday 4 2021-01-28 13:22:01
Friday 5 2021-01-29 13:22:01
```